# I want get sum in list except null by for loop using python

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a list that named 'ages'. I try this.

```
for n in ages:
    if not n:
        continue
        a = float(n)
    sum1 += a
```

But that only output lastone of the list. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Comment: `sum(float(e) for e in ages if e)`, however if your "nulls" are zeros just perform the sum, zeros won't change the result

Comment: Fix your indentation in the example:  Your conversion should be at the same tab level as the summation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit change and your sum result will be well

```py
for n in ages:
    if not n:
        continue
    a = float(n) # move left
    sum1 += a
```

Comment: thank u so much!!!!!

Comment: You actually don't need the intermediate variable `sum1 += float(n)` is sufficient